# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context - suggested fix not working

Tags: android

I have an alarm clock app - It works absolutely fine on my moto G3 running CM14, but on literally every other device I get this error:

```
Unable to start service joelizsoftware.david.slide_puzzle_alarm_clock.RingtoneService@69b5bb9 with Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=joelizsoftware.david.slide_puzzle_alarm_clock/.RingtoneService (has extras) }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I've followed advice from SO, and added in:

```
ringtoneIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

but I still get the same error. Any ideas?

```
public class Alarm_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        String extraString = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
        String prefString = intent.getExtras().getString("savePref");



        Intent ringtoneIntent = new Intent(context, RingtoneService.class);
        ringtoneIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        ringtoneIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        ringtoneIntent.putExtra("extra", extraString);
        ringtoneIntent.putExtra("savePref", prefString);



        context.startService(ringtoneIntent);

    }
}
```

It is ruining my Sunday

Comment: Move the `addFlags` line below the `setFlags` line and check if it works.

Comment: But you are not using startActivity

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is rather in `RingtoneService`. The `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag should be added to an activity intent, if you are starting it from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public class Alarm_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



String extraString = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
String prefString = intent.getExtras().getString("savePref");

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.RingtoneService");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    i.putExtra("extra", extraString);
    i.putExtra("savePref", prefString);
    context.startActivity(i);




context.startService(ringtoneIntent);

}
```